# PHP PhantomJS Custom Scripts

Tags: php, phantomjs

I want to parse a website, but first it has to be modified (by running some JavaScript events, e.g. open a collapse-box). I tried to solve it with PHP PhantomJS. But it does not work.

```
<?php

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\DependencyInjection\ServiceContainer;

$location = __DIR__ . "/../web/phantomjs";

$serviceContainer = ServiceContainer::getInstance();

$procedureLoader = $serviceContainer->get('procedure_loader_factory')
    ->createProcedureLoader($location);

$client = Client::getInstance();
$client->isLazy();
$client->setProcedure('procedure');
$client->getProcedureLoader()->addLoader($procedureLoader);

$request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

$request->setTimeout(5000);
$request->setMethod('GET');
$request->setUrl('http://jonnyw.me');

$client->send($request, $response);

if($response->getStatus() === 200) {
    echo $response->getContent();
}
```

*procedure.proc*

```
var page  = require('webpage').create();

page.open ('{{ input.getUrl() }}', '{{ input.getMethod() }}', '{{ input.getBody() }}', function (status) 
    // do something
    phantom.exit(1);
});

phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    phantom.exit(1);
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you specify what behavior you're observing and what you've tried while debugging.